# Why does my data form my word form don't save?

Tags: python, django, database, forms

So I have created a Form with an id and some words and now I wanted to store it in a DB table I have in my MySQL DB. But for some reason, when I hit the submit button the Object saves but there is no data in it.

my forms.py:

```py
class WordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    SessionID = forms.CharField(label= 'Session ID', 
        widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Please enter your session ID'
        }))
    Word1 = forms.CharField(label= 'Word1', 
        widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Enter First Word'
        }))
    Word2 = forms.CharField(label= 'Word2', 
        widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Enter Second Word'
        }))
    Word3 = forms.CharField(label= 'Word3', 
        widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Enter Third Word'
        }))

    Result = forms.CharField(label= 'Result', required=False, 
            widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': 'True'}))
    
    mode_selection = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MODE_SELECTION, label='Please Select an Option:', widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta:
        model = WordsTable
        fields = ('SessionID', 'Word1', 'Word2', 'Word3', 'Result')
```

my models.py:

```py
class WordsTable(models.Model):
    session_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='session_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    user_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='user_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    hour = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    run_label = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    word1 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    word2 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    word3 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    word4 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    word5 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'words_table'
```

my views.py:

```py
def index(request):
    form = WordForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        wordForm = form.save()
        return redirect('index')
    else:
       wordForm = WordForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'form.html', context)
```

my form.html:

```
<form class="word-form" method="POST" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2>Inputs</h2>
    {{form|crispy}}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Run</button>
</form>
```

I have worked with some tutorials but the data of the form just won't save. Help is much appreciated

Comment: How do you expect the form field `SessionID` to be linked to the models field `session_id`? And similarly other fields?

Comment: okay, and what should I do then? how do I connect those field to save the data?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't simply rename `SessionID` to `session_id` (similar for other fields)? The model form normally would do this matching automatically.

Comment: you're right, it worked, thank you so much!